# Adding inputs to a convolutional neural network after convolution and pooling layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a convolutional neural network which will contain a certain number of convolution and pooling layers. The problem is that i wanted to add some extra inputs after the feature extraction steps (convolution+pooling).

This extra inputs will be added to the flattened feature maps (first layer of the fully connected layer). I wanted to ask if is there any documentation to implement this, in tensorflow or (if i'm lucky) in keras.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such a model with `tf.keras.models.Model` class.

First, we can build the `tf.keras.models.Sequential` model for the Convolution and Pooling layers.

```
conv_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential( [ ... ] )
```

Then as you said, we need a fully connected Dense network. We create it similarly like the above model.

```
fc_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential( [ ... ] )
```

Then assemble the `Input` layers with the models we created.

```
input1 = Input( ... )
input2 = Input( ... )

cnn_output = conv_model( input1 )
output = fc_model( [ cnn_output , input2 ] )

model = tf.keras.models.Model( [ input1 , input2 ] , output )
```

Comment: thank you very much @Shubham Panchal, you made my day

Comment: Keras has this special ability that it can call Sequential models on Input layers and even other Sequential models as well. :-)